# "Product pdfCalligraph is unknown. Probably you have to register it" When i am trying to print Hindi Font using pdfCalligraph

Tags: c#, printing, pdf-generation, hindi

I am getting an error message when I add a paragraph to the document.
"iText.Commons.Exceptions.UnknownProductException: 'Product pdfCalligraph is unknown. Probably you have to register it"
How to fix?

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9H2hh.png)

Comment: That may be an issue with your license or with your dependencies. In the former case you may have to contact iText support.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I have written mail to support to get a draft license to verify my requirement then we will buy a license seeing the result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the license key json file for itext 7. Then you need to include the licensing libraries to your project.

[Installing the iText license key and license key library for Java and .NET](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/installation-guidelines/installing-the-itext-license-key-and-license-key-library-for-java-and-net)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31414483)